# How to include an overview map control code in qgis2web code

Tags: qgis2web, map-overviews

Please, forum I would like to know how to add an overview map control code in my qgis2web  generated OpenLayers code.If am not clear enough the link below demonstrates what I mean 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your exported OpenLayers map, and open `resources/qgis2web.js` in a text editor. Find the following line:

```
    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false}).extend([
```

Insert this line immediately after it:

```
        new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
```

Comment: I did as Tom suggests and the control is present and functional but there is no map image in the control??